# How can I change the value of the argument used in the 'for' loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop, global-variables

Using the combination of `for` and `while`, my problem is similar to this example: I want to add 1 to the first element of the vector x, skip elements 2:4 and add 1 to the fifth element until to the end of the vector x.

```
j <- 0
x <- c(rep(1, 4), 5:7)

for (i in 1:length(x)){
  x[i] <- x[i] + 1 
  while (j == 0){
    i <- i + 1
    if(x[i] != 1) j <- 1
    print(paste('in:', i))
  }
print(paste('out:', i))
}
```

the result shows that the i value do not change. Is it possible to change it in R?

```
[1] "in: 2"
[1] "in: 3"
[1] "in: 4"
[1] "in: 5"
[1] "out: 5"  # look!!!
[1] "out: 2"
[1] "out: 3"
[1] "out: 4"
[1] "out: 5"
[1] "out: 6"
[1] "out: 7"
```

Comment: ?"for" explains this in the Details section

Comment: thanks @baptiste! I did not know a could use ?"for"!!! I just tried ?for...

Comment: FYI this is nothing to do global or local variables.

Comment: tks @hadley. I edited the question.

Comment: @baptiste, with your comment I solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With @baptiste comment I solved the problem. As the help information states: "`next` halts the processing of the current iteration and advances the looping index". One solution given the example:

```
j <- 0
x <- c(rep(1, 4), 5:7)

for (i in 1:length(x)){
  if (x[i] == 1 & j == 0){
    x[i] <- x[i] + 1 
    j <- 1
    next
  } 
  if (x[i] == 1) next
  x[i] <- x[i] + 1 
}

x

[1] 2 1 1 1 6 7 8
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply

```
x + rep(c(1,0,0,0), length.out=length(x))
```

?

If you don't mind about recycling warnings, use this: `x + c(1,0,0,0)`.

Comment: tks @Ferdinand.kraft. But, as I mentioned in the question, my real problem is based in the use of the 'for' loop. This is just an example to show that I want to change the value of the 'for' argument.

Answer (score 0):

Or without warnings

```
x <- c(rep(1, 4), 5:7)
increment.position <- seq(1, length(x), by = 5)
x[increment.position] <- x[increment.position] + 1
```